# With JQuery, how can I target div elements with a specific inner text value for a "replaceWith" function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to replace  `<div class="simpleCart_grams">180 grams</div>` for all items in the list with this element `<div class="simpleCart_type">Edibles</div>` with a new div element `<div class='simpleCart_each'>1 Item</div>`.

Thanks!

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fmypjqu5/3/)

HTML

```
<div class="cartcontent">



        <div class="simpleCart_items"> 
    <div><div>
    <div class="headerRow"></div></div>

    <div class="itemRow row-0 odd" id="cartItem_3">
    <div class="item-remove">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">remove</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item-name">
    <a data-ajax="false" data-role="none" href="/shop_pages/catagories/products/products.php?PID=3&amp;QTY=14">
    <div class="simpleCart_name">Cali Orange</div>
    <div class="simpleCart_type">Sativa</div></a></div>

    <div class="item-weight">
    <div class="simpleCart_grams">14 grams</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-price">$175.00</div>
    </div>
    <div class="itemRow row-1 even" id="cartItem_6"><div class="item-remove">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">remove</a></div><div class="item-name">
    <a data-ajax="false" data-role="none" href="/shop_pages/catagories/products/products.php?PID=6&amp;QTY=14">
    <div class="simpleCart_name">Amnesia Jack</div>
    <div class="simpleCart_type">Sativa</div></a></div>
    <div class="item-weight"><div class="simpleCart_grams">14 grams</div></div>
    <div class="item-price">$175.00</div></div>






    <div class="itemRow row-2 odd" id="cartItem_105"><div class="item-remove">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">remove</a></div>
    <div class="item-name">

    <a data-ajax="false" data-role="none" href="/shop_pages/catagories/products/products.php?PID=105&amp;QTY=180">
    <div class="simpleCart_name">Blondie Bar</div>
    <div class="simpleCart_type">Edibles</div></a>
    </div><div class="item-weight">
    <div class="simpleCart_grams">180 grams</div></div>
    <div class="item-price">$80.00</div></div></div>
    </div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    where ($( '.simpleCart_type' ).text() === "Edibles") {

  $( "div.simpleCart_grams" ).replaceWith( "<div class='simpleCart_each'>1 Item</div>" );

  }


});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the jQuery [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector to get all elements that contain the specified text.

```
$('div.simpleCart_type:contains("Edibles")')
  .replaceWith( "<div class='simpleCart_each'>1 Item</div>" );
```

---

To filter out element with exact match use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) method.

```
$('div.simpleCart_type').filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().trim() == 'Edibles';
}).replaceWith( "<div class='simpleCart_each'>1 Item</div>" );
```

---

In your case the [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method returns the combined text content of elements so the if condition would fail(there is no `where` keyword in JavaScript), in order to make it work you need to check on the individual elements.

```
$('div.simpleCart_type' ).each(function(){
   if($(this).text() === "Edibles") {
      $(this).replaceWith( "<div class='simpleCart_each'>1 Item</div>" );
   }
});
```

---

**UPDATE :** Since you want to update the gram div, do something like this using [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) method.

```
$('div.simpleCart_grams').filter(function() {
  return $(this).closest('.itemRow').find('.simpleCart_type').text().trim() == 'Edibles';
}).replaceWith("<div class='simpleCart_each'>1 Item</div>");
```

```js
$('div.simpleCart_grams').filter(function() {
  return $(this).closest('.itemRow').find('.simpleCart_type').text().trim() == 'Edibles';
}).replaceWith("<div class='simpleCart_each'>1 Item</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cartcontent">



  <div class="simpleCart_items">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="headerRow"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="itemRow row-0 odd" id="cartItem_3">
        <div class="item-remove">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">remove</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-name">
          <a data-ajax="false" data-role="none" href="/shop_pages/catagories/products/products.php?PID=3&amp;QTY=14">
            <div class="simpleCart_name">Cali Orange</div>
            <div class="simpleCart_type">Sativa</div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item-weight">
          <div class="simpleCart_grams">14 grams</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-price">$175.00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemRow row-1 even" id="cartItem_6">
        <div class="item-remove">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">remove</a></div>
        <div class="item-name">
          <a data-ajax="false" data-role="none" href="/shop_pages/catagories/products/products.php?PID=6&amp;QTY=14">
            <div class="simpleCart_name">Amnesia Jack</div>
            <div class="simpleCart_type">Sativa</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-weight">
          <div class="simpleCart_grams">14 grams</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-price">$175.00</div>
      </div>






      <div class="itemRow row-2 odd" id="cartItem_105">
        <div class="item-remove">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">remove</a></div>
        <div class="item-name">

          <a data-ajax="false" data-role="none" href="/shop_pages/catagories/products/products.php?PID=105&amp;QTY=180">
            <div class="simpleCart_name">Blondie Bar</div>
            <div class="simpleCart_type">Edibles</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-weight">
          <div class="simpleCart_grams">180 grams</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-price">$80.00</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="itemRow row-2 odd" id="cartItem_105">
      <div class="item-remove">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">remove</a></div>
      <div class="item-name">

        <a data-ajax="false" data-role="none" href="/shop_pages/catagories/products/products.php?PID=105&amp;QTY=180">
          <div class="simpleCart_name">Black Mintr</div>
          <div class="simpleCart_type">Edibles</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item-weight">
        <div class="simpleCart_grams">120 grams</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-price">$80.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

---

Or with using jQuery [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) and [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector(not exact text match).

```
$('.itemRow:has(.simpleCart_type:contains("Edibles")) div.simpleCart_grams').replaceWith("<div class='simpleCart_each'>1 Item</div>");
```

```js
$('.itemRow:has(.simpleCart_type:contains("Edibles")) div.simpleCart_grams').replaceWith("<div class='simpleCart_each'>1 Item</div>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cartcontent">



  <div class="simpleCart_items">
    <div>
      <div>
        <div class="headerRow"></div>
      </div>

      <div class="itemRow row-0 odd" id="cartItem_3">
        <div class="item-remove">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">remove</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-name">
          <a data-ajax="false" data-role="none" href="/shop_pages/catagories/products/products.php?PID=3&amp;QTY=14">
            <div class="simpleCart_name">Cali Orange</div>
            <div class="simpleCart_type">Sativa</div>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="item-weight">
          <div class="simpleCart_grams">14 grams</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-price">$175.00</div>
      </div>
      <div class="itemRow row-1 even" id="cartItem_6">
        <div class="item-remove">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">remove</a></div>
        <div class="item-name">
          <a data-ajax="false" data-role="none" href="/shop_pages/catagories/products/products.php?PID=6&amp;QTY=14">
            <div class="simpleCart_name">Amnesia Jack</div>
            <div class="simpleCart_type">Sativa</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-weight">
          <div class="simpleCart_grams">14 grams</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-price">$175.00</div>
      </div>






      <div class="itemRow row-2 odd" id="cartItem_105">
        <div class="item-remove">
          <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">remove</a></div>
        <div class="item-name">

          <a data-ajax="false" data-role="none" href="/shop_pages/catagories/products/products.php?PID=105&amp;QTY=180">
            <div class="simpleCart_name">Blondie Bar</div>
            <div class="simpleCart_type">Edibles</div>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-weight">
          <div class="simpleCart_grams">180 grams</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-price">$80.00</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="itemRow row-2 odd" id="cartItem_105">
      <div class="item-remove">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="simpleCart_remove">remove</a></div>
      <div class="item-name">

        <a data-ajax="false" data-role="none" href="/shop_pages/catagories/products/products.php?PID=105&amp;QTY=180">
          <div class="simpleCart_name">Black Mintr</div>
          <div class="simpleCart_type">Edibles</div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item-weight">
        <div class="simpleCart_grams">120 grams</div>
      </div>
      <div class="item-price">$80.00</div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: updated [Fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/fmypjqu5/5/)  

I need the div element that contains the text "180 grams" to be replaced and say "1 item", instead of the text "edible".

Comment: @AaronTomlinson :  yes it's possible

Comment: this is a shopping cart list, so I need all the potential items in the cart, that carry the text "Edibles" to have the "grams div" replaced with "items number div".

Comment: updated [fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/fmypjqu5/8/) 

so here is what I mean, the 120 grams on the last row I added would also need to change.